# different between neo4j enterprise and neo4j community for windows?

Tags: neo4j

I've just started to learn the Neo4j graphs db. I have a question:

What is the difference between neo4j enterprise and neo4j community for windows?

Answer (score 9):

You can find a list of differences on [the price comparison overview](http://www.neotechnology.com/price-list/).

Features the Open Source version lacks are:

- High-Performance Cache
- Clustering
- Online Backup
- Advanced Monitoring

The paid licenses also come with a support contract (you can ask for help from people who will not downvote, edit or close your questions).

Answer (score 4):

Neo4j Enterprise just has more 'enterprise features' such as clustering and  additional security for example.   The comparison link the other poster provided is good to see the differences between enterprise and community server but it does not mention that Neo4j Enterprise is also free under it's open source license!  I would just focus on Neo4j server, not the new 'platform' they are now pushing.

If you don't want to play with their Neo4j Desktop under a trial agreement, you can go straight to Neo4j Enterprise server and run it. It starts the same way as the community edition and is open source under the [AGPLv3 license] https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html.

You can download Neo4j Enterprise versions before 3.3.0 from the  neo4j distribution site below. (3.2.8 is the last version that includes the AGPL license on their distribution site.)

http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-enterprise-3.2.8-windows.zip

OR

If you want to use the newest free Neo4j Enterprise edition (currently 3.3.1 as of today) then you can download the free open source binaries we package from source for our government clients at https://igovsol.com/downloads.html

Once you download the zip file to the following to get started. (Assuming you have JAVA setup on your windows machine.)

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/

1) Right-click the downloaded file, click Extract All.
Change directory to top-level extracted directory.

2) Run bin\neo4j console

3) Stop the server by typing Ctrl-C in the console.

The enterprise package is 100% free under it's open source AGPL license.

Unzip the package you download and you can verify it by looking at the LICENSE.txt

If you are curious about learning why you can't get the free AGPL binaries after 3.3.0 - checkout a blog post I wrote at https://blog.igovsol.com/2017/11/14/Neo4j-330-is-out-but-where-are-the-open-source-enterprise-binaries.html